# Do you say "the tree is shed in winter" to express all leaves on the tree fall off because of the weather in everyday conversation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

The Vietnamese-English dictionary suggests me to use "**[the tree is shed or nude](https://glosbe.com/vi/en/tr%E1%BB%A5i%20l%C3%A1)**" to express all leaves on the tree fall off because of the weather.

But I am not sure if we say it in everyday conversation.

Do you say "**the tree is shed in winter**"?

Answer (score 1):

**Shed** as a noun is a house or a barn like structure to keep things (workshop) or for animals.

**Shed** as a verb means the leaves or flowers of a tree to fall off.

So the correct sentence would be:

> The tree sheds (its leaves) in winter.
>
> The trees shed (their leaves) in winter.

[Source of the meanings](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shed)

You may also consider using the following sentence:

> The winter has left the tree **bare**.
>
> The leaf fall has left the tree **bare**.

[Source of the meaning](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bare)

Now, I am just a teenager, hence I cannot tell which word or phrase is more readily understandable by a child or toddler. This may well be answered by a someone elderly. But I can at least tell that the sentence using adjective ***bare*** can be comparatively difficult to understand.

Comment: I am looking a friendly word that children can understand. Is "Shed" common in everyday conversation?

Comment: Sorry, for which country are you in search of a friendly word? The place determines the ordinary usage. It is better for you to check your question out on the Ngram site.

Comment: As Dhanishtha says, we would use _bare_, not _nude_. The tree _has shed (or lost) its leaves_ or _the leaves have fallen off the tree_.